# I need a powerful disk retrieval tool

Tags: kubuntu, disk, tools

I have a disk which failed on another computer. I took it out and plugged it into this one (running kubuntu 17.10) via a usb port.

Nothing happens when it's plugged in. I checked dmesg, fdisk and testdisk. I didn't try gparted because it functions with the gnome interface. Kubuntu's equivalent, partitionmanager, doesn't see the disk.

I looked in `/dev/` but there is no sdc stuff. I see several sda, because I have several partitions.

```
/dev$ ls sd*
sda  sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5
```

Nothing changes when I plug this disk in or out. It's as if there was nothing at the end of the wire.

I need a way to tell the computer that it's there. Either with a konsole command line or through some disk recovery software.

I read that : "/dev/sdb1 will be a symlink to /dev/scsi/host5....
You can use the ln command to create a /dev/sdb1"

I have no /dev/scsi but I have several scsi folders. 
In /proc/scsi I have a file called device_info
There I can read (among others) :

```
'SEAGATE' 'ST157N' 0x1
'SEAGATE' 'ST296' 0x1
'SEAGATE' 'ST1581' 0x1
```

Could one of these correspond to my failing HD? The problem is that this info stays even if I unplug the HD...

All advice welcome.

Comment: There is no software that can fix broken hardware.

Comment: is it the electronics of the drive? or mechanics?    try using `smartctl` and see what data you can read from the drive (smartctl reads from the electronics & completely ignores the mechanical heads/platters/..)  If you still get nothing, I'd visually look for flaws (electrical connections, traces, caps, color (burnt)) etc but the nothing during this & quiet (no drive noise) could mean its the electronics... replacement board time  (if the data is worth the hassle - or just new disk & restore your backups)

Comment: Thank you. I tried : 
/dev$ smartctl --scan

But I got : 
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device    - - -   How can I replace the board?

Comment: Not that I expect you to get any different result, but I used to use GParted on Kubuntu -- worked fine, at least under 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase another hard drive that is the exact make and model (even if it is used) and swap the controller board. You have a extremely high chance of retrieving the data since most HDD failures is the controller board.

Comment: Update : unfortunately, the problem was not the board. I bought two and tried them both. I also had to buy a torx screwdriver. When plugged in, the disk spins, clicks, and then stops. It does this sequence twice and then nothing. I test it with "dmesg | tail". No messages at all relevant to the disk.

Comment: Any other ideas, please? Otherwise I'm thinking about sending this disk to hddsavers.com. They charge 350 dollars for a 2.5 inches disk of more than 80 GB.

Comment: I still think there is some improvement, because before I didn't hear anything...

Answer (score 0):

If "Nothing changes when I plug this disk in or out" the disk is dead as a Dodo ... unless you are able to persuade the electronics or motor in the disk to work - or pay someone to fix it, probably a hefty sum - your data is gone for good.

Comment: In this case, if I get another disk of the same brand and model, open both HD boxes in a dust-free environment, and swap the actual disks, it should function again, shoudn't it?

Comment: @AlainReve You'd be ahead to swap just the electronics board onto the capsule you're trying to recover.  The head clearance in modern drives is so small that a "clean room" is none too clean for handling the platters and heads -- and a simple touch on a head can misalign it enough to make it strike the platter surface.

Comment: I answered above. All other suggestions welcome.